# Monticello repository not committing methods(resources) of WAFileLibrary subclass

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside, monticello

I find that `WAFileLibrary` subclasses resource methods cannot be committed to Monticello repository. Is this normal? These resources have been added by the `WAFileLibrary->addFilesIn:` method. But when i try to create another method and then commit, i find that the new method gets committed and that i can load it on a different image without issues. So then i filed out the `WAFileLibrary` subclass , and removed it from the image, and then i again filed it in. After when i commit, all the resource method gets committed and its seems things are fine.

But why am i not able to commit it soon after creating the class , adding resources by addFilesIn: as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really unusual since resources are stored as methods. I do not see why you could not save them. What was the exact error message? Do you have a way to reproduce your problem? On which version are your working?

Comment: Version:Pharo2.0
Latest update: #20608 - I dont get any error messages. When i commit the package it says committed. but when i browse it from monticello or load it to another image. all my uploaded(using addFilesIn:) messages(resources) are missing.

Comment: To reporduce subclass a WAFileLibrary. Add a file with addAllFilesIn: . Then commit it to monticello. After browse it from monticello. all the uploaded protocol will be missing. But if i create another method say selectorsToInclude , then this alone will get committed. Also, if i file out my WAFileLibrary class , remove it from image, then file it in again, and after if i commit, i get all the methods committed to the repo. It sure is strange but the file out , remove , re-filein process is keeping me going..:-)

Comment: Ok I took seaside30, I added a subclass of WAFileLibrary. Then I did StefWAFileLibrary addAllFilesIn: 'foo' and I could see the method but I could see it when I saved the package! Then I did the same in Seaside3.1 and I got the same problem. I even did not see the same code in the created method. We should report this to the Seaside mailing-list.

Comment: I added new methods and I could version them but not the one originally loaded. I find that totally confusing. We should open a ticket on Pharo.

Comment: Yes i also thought so. i remember Bahman Movaqar from the squeak commutity too was reporting the same. I think this sould be taken forward. As i am new to pharo, i am not sure how to report this officially. I hope you can help me out there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I marked Stephanes response as answer since he has tried it out and confirmed that its something to be looked upon. So when this is resolved i hope to update here for other users.Thanks.